# copy only certain bytes of file?

Tags: bash, files

How can I copy a file, starting at $N bytes and onward?

I can use curl's `-r` option like this: `$ curl -r 41663- http://server.com/file.ext` to download from byte 41663 and onward, but how can I do this with a local file?   I could use split, and make each file the size of the offset I want, but that would just complicate thigns.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `dd` command. Sorry for the very short answer. You'll have to look it up in the manual. `man dd` will explain how it works.

Comment: This is the usual way to go for you. Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29

Comment: `dd if=input-file of=output-file skip=number-of-bytes bs=1`

Comment: The performance of `dd` command with option `bs=1` is very slow. so this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/58678/628876 should be much meaningful

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do this with the `tail` command's `-c` option:

```
-c, --bytes=K
       output the last K bytes; alternatively,  use  -c  +K  to  output
       bytes starting with the Kth of each file
```

So to do something similar to the curl invocation, you could do:

```
tail -c +41663 file.ext > copy.ext
```